# How to load a image from a URL into a viewpager

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager

i've searched the internet for this question and i couldn't find anything good.
I did look on the [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) Site but they 
load a image from a URL into a ImageView.

Here is my code:

Openfactsscreen activity :

```
public class Openfactsscreen extends Activity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_openfactsscreen); 

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        public void openmenu(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SendFact.class);
        startActivity(intent); }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.openfactsscreen, menu);
        return true;
 }

}
```

ImageAdapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.factcard2,
        R.drawable.factcard8,
        R.drawable.factcard4
        };



        ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }


}
```

activity_openfactsscreen :

```
    <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundotheractivities" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/factsscreen_layout" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/emailbutton"
        android:onClick="openmenu" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:background="@drawable/informationbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything works fine, if anyone knows a good site to look on or if anyone wants to help me that would be great!

Anyway thanks for your time and have nice day!

Comment: I don't have them, i don't know how i should start.

Comment: what do mean by you don't have them?

Comment: I do have the links ready but i don't have the code for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this at end of your Class `

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.factcard2,
        R.drawable.factcard8,
        R.drawable.factcard4
        };



        ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        //imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

        new LoadImage(imageView).execute("Your URL");

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }



     private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
            ImageView img=null;
            public LoadImage(ImageView img){
                this.img=img;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
                if(image != null){
                    img.setImageBitmap(image);
                }
            }
        }`
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! When i change imageview.setImageResource line and add yours it gives me this error :  
The method execute(String...) in the type AsyncTask<String,String,Bitmap> is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: GalImages[position] returns String url format is in it?

Comment: No i just changed the line with yours

Comment: Replace GalImages[position] with url you want!

Comment: it should be new LoadImage(imageView).execute("Your Url");

Comment: I just did but eclipse keeps giving me errors, "insert ; and insert ) to complete" But even if do that the errors keep coming .?

Comment: you should add class out side of your class

Comment: can you move this inside the class? and  try it!

Comment: Thank you! It works great! I really appreciate it! But i have 1 one more question left, when i add multiple links to the code (because that's my goal, using the swipe to show images) it will show the images from the url like a diashow. It changes every 2 seconds

Comment: yes you cant get image from UI thread it has to be set in separate thread. if my answer fixes your issue mark it as accepted answer. :)

Comment: Hi, is there any way i could contact you?

Comment: I want to learn some things, and you seem like the perfect teacher. Well ofcourse only if you have time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple code :

```
    URL url = new URL("yourURL");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Otherwise you can look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288544/4385913)

Also you can try this :

```
 try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(URL).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It gives me a error at : 
Syntax error on token "bmp", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token, and 
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: Try `public static Bitmap bmp` or just `public BitMap bmp`

Comment: Thanks for your time, It still gives me a error, it says i have to add "}" but when i do that it doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you try my two answers? Did you see the post of the link?

Comment: Yes i looked at it and i tried both of your answers